# Transfer parameters between train steps

Tags: database, jsf, oracle-adf

I have a custom PL/SQL function that i am calling through a page in ADF that inserts data in a database. I want to create a train, with two steps in order to separate my parameters. In the first step put one parameter of my function and in the other step the other and then call my function. It seems that it doesn't work because it only gets the second parameter.

Any hints how to accomplish getting both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your parameters to pageFlowScope as you go, and use them in the last train step

Comment: How to save in pageFlowScope?

Comment: If you have train buttons you can add setPropertyListener like described in this article [http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/using-diferent-vos-for-master-detail-navigation/] and save it in the pageFlowScope

Comment: Sorry, here is the url http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/using-diferent-vos-for-master-detail-navigation/

Comment: When i bind the propertyListener to the train button it says javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ADF_FACES-60074!

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'pageFlow' scope ManagedBean and store there the attribute values that you want to save and use on different steps of the flow. I have used this approach with my ADF applications and everything is fine.